# Order by XML node value in PostgreSQL

Tags: xml, postgresql

Is there a way to use `order by` functionality with values from an XML column in PostgreSQL?

## Example

If I have this xml as a column in my PostgreSQL database in a XML column, is there a way to write a `select` statement to order the results by `<type>` attribute?

```
<items>
 <item>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>Item #1</name>
  <type>Hardware</type>
 </item>
 <item>
  <id>2</id>
  <name>Item #2</name>
  <type>Software</type>
 </item>
</items>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to get necessary XML elements with [`xpath()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-xml.html) function 1st. Then get processed all result values as TEXT type for further ordering (You are not able to apply `GROUP BY` identifier to Postgres `XML` type). Actual query may be the following:

```
WITH extracted_data AS (
   SELECT id,unnest(xpath('//type/text()',data))::TEXT AS item_type  
   FROM xml_test
) 
SELECT id,item_type FROM extracted_data 
ORDER BY id,item_type DESC;
```

Example DDL and data:

```
-- Sample DDL
CREATE TABLE xml_test (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  data XML
);
-- Sample Data
INSERT INTO xml_test(data) VALUES
  ('<items>
      <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Item #1</name>
        <type>Hardware</type>
      </item>
      <item>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Item #2</name>
        <type>Software</type>
      </item>
    </items>'::XML),
('<items>
      <item>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>Item #3</name>
        <type>Middleware</type>
      </item>
      <item>
        <id>4</id>
        <name>Item #4</name>
        <type>Other</type>
      </item>
    </items>'::XML);
```

Comment: Thank you it was very easy :)